# How to POST a JSON string that includes an image path, using okhttp3

Tags: java, python, json, android-studio, okhttp

I have a JSON string like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "pk": 1,
    "title": "T1",
    "description": "D1",
    "photo": "http://127.0.0.1:8888/media/myposts/2019/2/6/a9811ca2-cdd7-400b-805a-efe4be22b3f5.png",
    "price": 2000.0,
    "catagory": "S",
    "viewnum": 15,
    "timestamp": "2019-02-06T19:43:26.754464Z"
}
```

that I need to send to server. If I didnt have the "photo" field, some thing like the following will work:

```
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, new Gson().toJson(obj));

            post_request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url_str)
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "")
                    .build();
```

however I am not quite sure how this is doable when we have "photo" field. I am using okhttp3,

I would do something similar in python by :

```
requests.request("Post",  Base_URL + ENDPOINT_REST, data=data, files=file_data, headers=headers)
```

where data is JSON string without "photo" field and "photo field will be passed in file_data:

```
        with open(image_path, 'rb') as image:
            file_data = {
                'image': image
            }
```

I guess some simmilar logic should be at Java as well. I was wondering if someone could help me
Thank you

Comment: It looks like you are trying to send the image contents in the JSON payload? If so, the "photo" will need to be a base64 representation of the image

Comment: So, just be sure, you definitely don't wish to send the file via url, but wish to send the binary? It seems that way, but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: The better approach would be to do two different posts. First, upload the image and create the URL to which the image is uploaded and then do the JSON post. Sending an Image as part of a field in JSON would not be great practice.

Comment: To clarify, what I expect to happen, is to upload the png file into a media folder, and have the uri stored for that record (like json example in question). so database just keeps the uri.